# {past tense verb} [optional adverb] is... - what is this grammar?

Tags: prepositions, past-tense, complements

I came across with this sentence

> **Located on the Trusted Server** is a private key named Certificate Authority (CA)

I guess it's another way to say something like: "**The thing that is located on the Trusted Server** is a private key named Certificate Authority (CA)"

Am I right? and how do I call this kind of grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is the prepositioning of the complement of a be verb. When the complement of a be verb goes right in front of its sentence, the main verb phrase and the subject switch places.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more? I don't understand when exactly I can switch the verb phrase and the subject. Can you give me some examples?

Comment: adj./n./participle phrase + (auxiliary)+be+Subject+the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Happy will be the wedding day./Swimming in the pool was John./A cook might have been Sarah.

Comment: And note that when the be verb is a finite verb and the complement is a noun(phrase/clause), the verb agrees with the complement, on its left; not the subject, on its right.

Comment: A problem is Sam and Michael. (not, A problem are Sam and Michael.)

Comment: When the complement of a be verb that is the main verb goes right in front of its sentence, you must make the inversion.